# php bitwise XOR and js bitwise XOR producing different results

Tags: javascript, php, bit-manipulation

When I try to perform bitwise XOR operation in php and js, they are producing different results in some cases , for example

```
2166136261 ^ 101 = -2128831072 on browsers (js)
2166136261 ^ 101  = 2166136224(php)
```

My understanding is because php is running 64 bit as opposed to 32 bit js.

Can anyone tell me the exact reason and if this could be solved so that both operations result in same value. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154381/javascript-php-xor-equivalent

Comment: There is no problem. This is the same result, just interpreted differently.

Comment: @harold, Ok, then how to make that same result look like as PHP's result?

Comment: @Green you can make it look unsigned with `>>> 0`, if you continue with other integer operation it'll just go back to signed again so it's mostly (but not entirely) a cosmetic change.

Answer (score -1):

2,147,483,647 is the biggest possible positive value for an integer in 32 bit computing, (it's 2^16, half of the 32 bits we have, the other half are reserved for negative numbers.)

Once you use a number bigger than that in a 32 bit system you start getting screwy results as the computer thinks it's a negative number. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)