# Why is this simple JavaScript XOR encryption algorithm not working?

Tags: javascript, xor

I am trying to develop a (*very*) simple XOR encryption algorithm in JavaScript.

In PHP, the following encryption algorithm works as expected:

```
function encryptXor($text, $key) {
  $result = '';

  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++)
    $result[$i] = $text[$i] ^ $key[$i % strlen($key)];

  return $result;
}
```

However, the following JavaScript algorithm does not work properly:

```
function encryptXor(text, key) {
  var result = '';

  for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    result += text.charAt(i) ^ key.charAt(i % key.length);

  return result;
}
```

A test case follows:

```
Text: someRandomText
Key:  123456789
PHP output: B]^QgWY\V\fVLA
JS output:  12345678912345
```

Apparently, the `^` operator is behaving differently between the two languages.

I have found some questions regarding the difference between PHP's and JavaScript's `^` operators, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154381/javascript-php-xor-equivalent), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344521/php-bitwise-xor-vs-javascript-bitwise-xor) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234130/php-bitwise-xor-and-js-bitwise-xor-producing-different-results), but I still could not resolve this issue.

Why is this JavaScript algorithm not working as expected?

---

*Minor note 1:* Since it is not possible to iterate over the characters of a string and replace them one by one in JavaScript, I used the `+=` operator inside the `for` loop in order to append the output of each XOR operation to the `result` variable.

*Minor note 2:* In order to normalize the character set, the functions actually return `base64_encode($result)` and `btoa(result)` in PHP and JS, respectively. Then, in order to decrypt it, the `decryptXor()` functions have to decode the `result` variables before iterating over them. Nonetheless, since this is not relevant to the question, I simplified the functions a bit. In this case, for the purpuses of testing, it is safer to use only alphanumeric characters in the `text` variable and only numerals in the `key` variable (or vice-versa).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need some other methods, like [`String#charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) or [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) for getting the same result.

The main problem is, you need a numerical value instead of the character/string.

```js
function encryptXor(text, key) {
    var result = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        result += String.fromCharCode(text.charCodeAt(i) ^ key.charCodeAt(i % key.length));
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(encryptXor('someRandomText', '123456789')); // B]^QgWY\V\fVLA
```

A bit shorter version

```js
function encryptXor(text, key) {
    return Array.from(
        text,
        (c, i) => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt() ^ key.charCodeAt(i % key.length))
    ).join('');
}

console.log(encryptXor('someRandomText', '123456789')); // B]^QgWY\V\fVLA
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that you are using [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) instead of [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt). `'someRandomText'.charAt(0)` evaluates to `'s'`. `'s' ^ x === x`, since the `^` operator attempts to convert both operands to numbers and `Number('s')` is `NaN`. So when you xor with any character other than a numeric one you just get the value of the key.

You also have another problem regarding Note 1: You can't just append to a string. If your algorithm results in the string '567' it's impossible to know whether that was created from concatenating '56' and '7' or '5' and '67'. That becomes a much bigger problem as the string gets longer. You could use an array instead of a string or left zero pad each substring to the same length or as Nina suggested, you could convert the result of the XOR back to a single char with [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).